# Flex позиционирование блоков

Tags: css, flexbox

Народ как с помощью flex расположить блоки помечены красними рамками в таком порядке как на картинке?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]    1

```css
*,
*::after,
*::before{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container{
  max-width: 1140px;
  margin: 0 auto; 
}

.clearfix::after{
  content: '';
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.product_item--float{
  float: left;
  margin-right: 30px;
}

.product_link{
  display: block; 
}
```

```html
 <div class="section2">
    <div class="container">
      <h2>Каталог круизов</h2>
      <span>Сортировать круизы по цене</span>

      <div class="product__block">
        <div class="product_item product_item--float">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/555x437" alt="">
          <a class="product_link" href="#">Морской круиз в Анапу</a>
          <p class="product_p">Маршрут: Сочи-Лазаревское-Геленджик-Анапа<br>
            Продолжительность: 10 ч. 0 мин.</p>
          <span class="product_price">49 000 руб.</span>
        </div>

        <div class="product_item">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/555x113" alt="">
          <a class="product_link" href="#">Обзорная морская прогулка с экскурсией</a>
          <p class="product_p">Маршрут: Сочи-Адлер-Сочи (без высадки)<br>
            Продолжительность: 1 ч. 0 мин.</p>
          <span class="product_price">5 000 руб.</span>
          <span class="product_price-old">15000 руб.</span>
        </div>
        <div class="product_item clearfix">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/555x113" alt="">
          <a class="product_link" href="#">Морская прогулка в Геленджик</a>
          <p class="product_p">Маршрут: Сочи-Туапсе-Геленджик<br>
            Продолжительность: 12 ч. 30 мин.</p>
          <span class="product_price">7 000 руб.</span>
          <span class="product_price-old">10000 руб.</span>
        </div>

        <div class="product_item product_item--float">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/555x215" alt="">
          <a class="product_link" href="#">Морской круиз в Новороссийск</a>
          <p class="product_p">Маршрут: Сочи-Геленджик-Новороссйиск-Геленджик-Сочи<br>
            Продолжительность: 13 ч. 0 мин.</p>
          <span class="product_price">14 800 руб</span>
        </div>
        <div class="product_item">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/555x215" alt="">
          <a class="product_link" href="#">Морская прогулка в Абрау-Дюрсо  </a>
          <p class="product_p">Маршрут: Сочи-Абрау-Дюрсо<br>
            Продолжительность: 11 ч. 0 мин.</p>
          <span class="product_price">14 800 руб</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <a class="blue__btn" href="#">Больше круизов</a>
    </div>
```

[image: так должно быть на планшете, а на мобильном все эти блоки в один ряд]

так должно быть на планшете, а на мобильном все эти блоки в один ряд

Comment: Здравствуйте. Оно и действительно, как с помощью flex расположить блоки? Только где блоки-то? - чтобы были блоки, вам нужно выложить свой код, ведь здесь просто некая картинка. А вы ведь спрашиваете, как блоки с помощью flex расположить, следовательно вы знаете, как их можно расположить подобным образом но без flex. Вот и предлагаю вам, выложите свой код с блоками и посмотрим как вы их расположили без флексов, чтобы нам помочь сделать тоже самое, но с флексами. Ведь такой вопрос-картинка провоцирует абсурдные ответы. Большие ли эти блоки и что там с адаптивом? Пока минус ставлю, увы.

Comment: Добавил код, как я сделал с помощу float

Answer (score 1):

Без дополнительных оберток можно сделать фиксированную высоту, колоночное расположение и перенос.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

div {
  border: 1px solid;
  height: 100px;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 1em;
}

section {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 200px;
}

.big {
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class=big>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

html:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="49000"></div>
  <div class="subwrapper">
    <div class="5000"></div>
    <div class="7000"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-start; /* space-between, еще как-нибудь*/
  align-items: stretch;
}

.subwrapper,
.49000, 
.5000,
.7000 {
  flex-basis: 50%;
}

.subwrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start; /* space-between, еще как-нибудь*/
  align-items: stretch;
}
```

Comment: Здравствуйте. Сразу же виден промах, зачем-то для `.wrapper` пишется `align-items: stretch;` когда это является значением по умолчанию: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_align-items.asp  Аналогично `flex-direction: row;` и `justify-content: flex-start;` идут по-умолчанию, зачем же мы их пишем? Ваш пример - это отличный путь запутать новичка. Рекомендую доработать ваш пример, а пока минус поставлю, увы. Отредактируете, тогда уберу минус. Еще рекомендую сделать запускаемый код, вместо картинок: https://placeholder.com/ Всего вам доброго.

Comment: @Alexandr Kazakov значение по умолчанию говорите. А  я считаю явное лучше неявного, в своем коде всегда пишу. За минус спасибо. Добра Вам. Ответ я редактировать не собираюсь, т.к. писал его в соответствии со своими представлениями о необходимом содержании, на которые не влияет обещание кого-либо великодушно убрать свой авторитетный минус. Если у Вас есть альтернативное виденье, то это прекрасная возможность дать свой вариант ответа. Если автор вопроса примет его как верный, это будет лучшим подтверждением Вашей точки зрения на полноту и достаточность ответов. 876a76ab12f56017a5bc47da7c4ca15e.

Comment: `А я считаю явное лучше неявного, в своем коде всегда пишу` Да нет же, не пишите. Вы ведь не пишите у всех подряд элементов padding: 0, border: none, margin: 0 и так далее. Вы ведь не пишите это у тех элементов, у которых данные свойства и так равняются 0, верно? Ведь тогда даже тегу `span` вы должны прописывать целый набор свойств, чтобы явно обозначить, что там например нет отступов. Но вы ведь так не делаете... Да ладно вам, признайте просто, что ваш опыт в Flexbox не достаточно велик, вы сами порой путаетесь в нужных свойствах, поэтому и написали все подряд.

Comment: Продолжу. Тогда каждому классу у <div> тега нужно прописывать `display: block;` а каждому <span> `display: inline;` И пусть они таковыми по умолчанию являются, чтобы нам явно это обозначить, мы у каждого тега пропишем. Я так и представляю, у каждого div с отдельным классом прописать: display: block; border:none; margin: 0; padding: 0; height: auto; width: auto; position: static; и так далее, длинный список у нас получится. Ну а что, зато явно пропишем, соберем все значения по умолчанию и их пропишем, и так для каждого класса.

Comment: `Что ты ко мне примотался` Да нет, здесь ведь сообщество, группа людей, мы здесь затем и собрались, что бы обсуждать, учиться. Я просто себя вспомнил, когда только переходил на флексы(до этого пользовался float-ами и bootstrap-3), казалось сложновато, потому что столько новых стилей появилось, я также записывал все подряд, что идет даже по умолчанию. У вас увидел, что из 9 пунктов, прописаны 5, что идут по умолчанию и которые вообще можно не писать, вот и решил высказаться. Я вас понял, больше писать здесь не буду. С миром. Хорошего вам дня.

Comment: @Alexandr Kazakov просто интересно. Вы ответ правильным считаете опустив все семантические тонкости?

Comment: Я считаю ответ правильным. Ведь все же заработает так как нужно задавшему вопрос. Просто интересно. Не желаете поставить плюс ответу господина BraFik?

Comment: @midia Здравствуйте. На ваш вопрос я не дам ответ, потому что вопрос заведомо задается некорректно. `семантические тонкости` - причем здесь семантика мне вообще непонятно, а почему это вы называете тонкостями? Я выше уже написал,что из 9 пунктов записанных в данном примере, 5(!) идут по умолчанию и их вообще без надобности писать. Если когда в CSS коде больше половины свойств прописаны впустую и это вы называете "тонкости" дело ваше, я это тонкостями не считаю, тем более когда это рекомендуется новичкам. Я например весь CSS код пишу по алфавиту, это можно назвать тонкостями. Всего вам доброго.

Comment: @AlexandrKazakov Ну может автор вопроса и не новичек:) А `семантические тонкости` - пишу со стороны muturgan. Ведь самое разумное объяснение наличия дефолтных свойств - дело привычки(может для него таким образом код читабельней становится или же может он действительно недавно начал изучать flexbox и дефолтные свойства являются в первую очередь для него самого семантическими напоминая как будет вести себя тот или иной блок). Я никого не оправдываю и не осуждаю я бы тоже их не писал бы. Но тем не менее как бы свойства по умолчанию не назывались бы (семантикой или же бесполезным кодом)

Comment: я с уважением попросил вас их опустить ожидая услышать конструктивный ответ на счет самой идеи реализации так как считаю вас опытным человеком во фронтэнде видел и сам получал от вас хорошие ответы на вопросы по теме. Вам тоже всего доброго;)

Comment: @midia `Ведь самое разумное объяснение наличия дефолтных свойств - дело привычки` Мы не должны обсуждать какую-то абстрактную ситуацию, какую-то абстрактную верстку с ее CSS кодом. В реальной работе CSS код может занимать немало строк кода, а зачастую он занимает их много. И вот для того чтобы в нем было легче и быстрее разбираться, нам конечно не следует его растягивать до еще большего объема за счет написания совершенно ненужных свойств. Так дело обстоит, зачем нам еще разглагольствовать. Нужно стремиться к компактности кода, чтобы все было только по делу, а не наоборот.

Comment: @midia `я с уважением попросил вас их опустить ожидая услышать конструктивный ответ`- посмотрите пожалуйста мой комментарий к вопросу вначале. Автор вопроса не только не привел свой код для примера, он даже задание нормально объяснить не смог, чтобы сделали за него. Нужно знать размер этих блоков,реализацию адаптива и что там с отступами у блоков, только тогда что-то можно порекомендовать. Сейчас же лучшим решением я вижу - заминусовать вопрос и закрыть его до того момента, пока автор не приведет его к должному виду.

Comment: `И вот для того чтобы в нем было легче и быстрее разбираться, нам конечно не следует его растягивать до еще большего объема за счет написания совершенно ненужных свойств.` полностью с вами согласен но понимание этого приходит со временем. Каждый из нас когда то впервые открывал htmlbook знакомясь с head и body:)

Comment: `посмотрите пожалуйста мой комментарий к вопросу вначале`  ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй так

```css
.news div {
  background-color: #f0f;

}

.news .inside div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #f00;
}

.news {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="news">
  <div>123456</div>
  <div class="inside">
    <div>111</div>
    <div>222</div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

bonus.
 html:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="49000"></div>
  <div class="5000"></div>
  <div class="7000"></div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr; /* не очень наглядно. чтобы сделать .5000 в 2 раза больше .7000 надо написать  2fr 1fr */
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr; /* не очень наглядно. чтобы сделать .49000 в 2/5 ширины враппера, а .5000 и .7000 3/5 ширины враппер, надо написать  2fr 3fr */
  grid-template-areas: 
    "a b"
    "a c";
  justify-items: stretch;
  align-items: stretch;
  align-content: stretch;
}

.49000 {
  grid-area: a;
}

.5000 {
  grid-area: b;
}

.7000 {
  grid-area: c;
}
```

Comment: Где-то здесь должен быть флексбокс.

Comment: Кому должен то?

Comment: Если не жонглировать словами, то это было условие автора вопроса, которое он явно указал как в теле вопроса, так и в тегах к нему.